# How calling zmq_poll() leads to calling zmq_abort()?

Tags: c++, c, zeromq

I'm using zmq version 4.2.2. My program crashes because of a call to `zmq_abort()` which calls `abort()`. According to stack trace, if I understand correctly, `zmq_abort()` is called from `src/socket_poller.cpp:54`. However, that line is the beginning of the function definition:

`zmq::socket_poller_t::~socket_poller_t ()`

The function does not have direct calls to `zmq_abort()` or any assert macros that would call it. There are not many asserts or any direct calls to `zmq_abort()` in the whole file either. However, other lines in the stack trace seem to match the source code in github:

https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/v4.2.2/src/socket_poller.cpp#L54

How does execution end up in `zmq_abort()`?

Beginning of stack trace:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f12cc9d4700 (LWP 23680))]
(gdb) where
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007f12ce123415 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#2  0x00007f12ce8db9c9 in zmq::zmq_abort (errmsg_=<optimized out>) at ../zeromq-4.2.2/src/err.cpp:87
#3  0x00007f12ce918cbe in zmq::socket_poller_t::~socket_poller_t (this=0x7f12c8004150, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../zeromq-4.2.2/src/socket_poller.cpp:54
#4  0x00007f12ce91793a in zmq_poller_destroy (poller_p_=0x7f12cc9d2af8)
    at ../zeromq-4.2.2/src/zmq.cpp:1236
#5  0x00007f12ce917e14 in zmq_poller_poll (timeout_=<optimized out>, nitems_=2, items_=0x1)
    at ../zeromq-4.2.2/src/zmq.cpp:854
#6  zmq_poll (items_=items_@entry=0x7f12cc9d2c20, nitems_=nitems_@entry=2, timeout_=timeout_@entry=5000)
    at ../zeromq-4.2.2/src/zmq.cpp:866
```

Comment: It could be that the socket is destroyed before zmq_poller.

Comment: Very difficult to diagnose this without some of your code.  Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zmq_abort()` was called from an assertation macro in `signaler_t`'s destructor:
https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/v4.2.2/src/signaler.cpp#L143. The `signaler_t` object is a member of `socket_poller_t`. I don't know for sure why the call to the destructor is not shown in the stack trace.

I was trying not to ask (directly) what was wrong with my code because it was infeasible to provide a code sample, but I'll mention that it turned out to be that a file descriptor was erroneously closed twice in another thread. Between the two close operations, zmq_poll() created a `socket_poller_t` object. `signaler_t`'s constructor opened an `eventfd`, which was the same fd (number) that had been closed earlier. Then, the other thread closed the same fd again, leading the destructor to get EBADF on close() and call`zmq_abort()`.